How to efficiently compute similarity scores for prefixes of a string with another string in C?
I'm working on a problem involving string matching where I need to compute the similarity scores for each prefix of a string C against another string S. The similarity score for a prefix P of C and S is defined as the product of two metrics:
1. Hit Count (H): The number of occurrences of P in S.
2. Plagiarism Likelihood (L): The number of times a substring is both a prefix and a suffix of P.
Given the constraints that both C and S can be up to 5*10^6 characters long, I am looking for an efficient way to perform these calculations, and time limit is 3 sec (ideally aiming for a time complexity of O(|S| + |C|)).
I initially considered using the KMP (Knuth-Morris-Pratt) algorithm for counting the occurrences of each prefix in S, but I am unsure how to efficiently compute L for each prefix without excessive recomputation.
Specific Questions:
1. Is there an efficient algorithm or a combination of algorithms that can help achieve this complexity for both computing H and L?
2. How can dynamic programming be applied to compute the L values efficiently for each prefix?
Any insights or suggestions on how to tackle this problem would be greatly appreciated!
Update on the Calculation of Plagiarism Likelihood (L)
I would like to provide further clarification on the computation of "Plagiarism Likelihood (L)" for a better understanding and accurate assistance. Here is the revised and more precise definition:
Definition: For a given string R, the Plagiarism Likelihood (L) is defined as the count of all prefixes of R that are also suffixes of R. Mathematically, it can be expressed as:
L(R) = |{k : 1 ≤ k ≤ |R| and R[1 : k] ⊐ R}|.

Calculation Across Substrings:
We need to calculate this metric for every possible prefix of the string C, ranging from C[1:1] to C[1:|C|]. This requires evaluating the Plagiarism Likelihood for each substring progressively as we increase the prefix length.

Rather than hunting for an efficient algorithm, the engineer's approach is to make something that works and then improve it where necessary. You have a defined problem already with defined subproblems (H and L, though I assume you meant for L "being a prefix or suffix of S", not P). If those subproblems seem large, break them down into further subproblems. Then you'll localize the part that truly needs the optimization.

Regarding L specifically: more clarity/examples surrounding the exact behavior desired here would help. There are certainly optimizations that could be made, but they require a correct understanding of the problem (less I optimize away something that shouldn't have been).

On the contrary, @Rogue, coding challenges such as this tend to be all about choosing a good algorithm for the job.  If you choose one that is not efficient enough then it's unlikely that incremental improvements will suffice to bring it up to snuff.  And in the real world, a good engineer starts with at least a sense of the relevant performance requirements, and uses that to inform their initial choice of algorithm.  Do not confuse detail-level code tweaking -- which indeed, can be deferred until it is needed -- with good high-level design.

@JohnBollinger indeed and agreed, sometimes nuance is lost in a comment box. I think the relevancy of choosing a performant algorithm (some task solving a singular problem) is less important from a business perspective: you get your concept up and running, and design the performance-critical components in a way that they can be substituted with better implementations down the line. But this is a broad topic that can be argued differently at different conceptual layers of application design, my original comment was to drive home "getting your feet wet".
